# How to refresh the Table of contents in qgis using python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2

I have 3 layers in the TOC in QGIS. I want to refresh the layers in the TOC to see what layers are present. Because, when I am executing the following code, I am not getting the layers present in QGIS.

```
layers = canvas.layers()
```

So I want to refresh the layers present in the TOC and check. How can I do that in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which layers are in the layer tree, it's preferable to query the layer tree and not the canvas ;)

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers()
```

[QgsProject.layerTreeRoot()](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#ac7b2f41c3507cbe1e2038eaeafbae1bf)

and

[QgsLayerTreeGroup.findLayers()](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeGroup.html#ab704d9e538f57f0637e3bb63ba7f7969)

You can then use its layer() method to get the "real" layer

```
[l.layer() for l in QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers()]
```

Or the layer's name() method to get the names

```
[l.layer().name() for l in QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers()]
```

Comment: but i  also want the names of the layers present in the toc.